# How the subdomain keep the full url of the url that it is redirecting to?

Tags: wordpress, azure, redirect, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I am not sure about the title of my question so let me an explain the situation with example:

I have a wordpress website at: [wwww.mywebsite.com](http://wwww.mywebsite.com)
(DNS: Godaddy, hosted on Azure, SSL enabled)

I setup a forum website hosted on another Azure account with a url like: [myforum.azurewebsites.net](http://myforum.azurewebsites.net)

I want to have a subdomain "forum" ([forum.mywebsite.com](http://forum.mywebsite.com)) to redirect to the forum website. I managed to achieve the redirection by using Godaddy subdomain settings. I also enabled the masking so the user see the [forum.mywebsite.com](http://forum.mywebsite.com) on the browser.

The problem is that the forum url does not show the subfolders url. For instance if someone wants to login, the user should see: [forum.mywebsite.com/login](http://forum.mywebsite.com/login) but the user only sees: [forum.mywebsite.com](http://forum.mywebsite.com)

How can I achieve the redirection in a way that the url keeps the subfolder path as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to set the custom domain on Azure which will require you to create a CNAME record in your DNS on Godaddy for forum.mywebsite.com that has the value of myforum.azurewebsites.net

Comment: That is right, I created a CNAME record (in Godaddy -> name: forum, value: myforum.azurewebsites.net) and added a custom domain (forum.mywebsite.com) in Azure portal.